# Spring Integration - setting dynamic queue name

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I create dynamic queue based on the job instance id. For request queue, I am able to override xml config & set the queue name as `jmsTemplateRequest.setDefaultDestination(jobid)` in java code for xml config mentioned as below.
 For response queue, I want a solution. Cause I am not able to set `jms-template` attribute for `jms:inbound-channel-adapter` programmatically.

```xml
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="RequestsChannel" jms-template="jmsTemplateRequest"/>
<bean id="RequestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="RequestsQueue" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplateRequest" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="RequestQueue"/>

    <!-- OTHERWISE how can I modify queue name in below code in java by autowiring? -->
     <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                        channel="ReplyChannel"
                                        destination-name="ReplyQueue"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The message-driven adapter doesn't use a `JmsTemplate`.

You would have to construct the adapter using java `@Configuration` instead of using XML.

You need two `@Bean`s - a `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` and a `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` which is passed into the endpoint in a constructor.

You could also use property placeholders or a SpEL expression instead...

```
destination-name="#{someBean.replyDestination}"
```

would call `getReplyDestination()` on `someBean`.

Comment: I can not put @Value(value="somevalue") private String queueName; "somevalue" will be dynamic

Comment: Could you give an example to pass from java to xml. somevalue above is dynamic. I have to set this way. queueName=getJobId(); sorry if I am not into that much level

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to provide much more context.

Comment: XML side ok. Java side can you give example how it should look like if I set the value in a method like queueName=getJobId()

Comment: In xml, I have like this:  <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="someChannel" destination-name="#{bean.destinationName}"/>   In java: I have like this: private String destinationName;  public void setDestinationName(String destinationName) {
  this.destinationName = destinationName;
 }
 public String getDestinationName() {
  return destinationName;
 }
    public void someMethod() { setDestinationName(getJobId());}

Comment: In xml, I have like this:      <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="someChannel" destination-name="#{bean.destinationName}"/>                                       In java: I have like this: private String destinationName;  public void setDestinationName(String destinationName) {
  this.destinationName = destinationName;
 }
 public String getDestinationName() {
  return destinationName;
 }
    public void someMethod() { setDestinationName(getJobId());}  where I am missing?

Comment: I mean how can I change destinationValue below each time programmatically when I run: @Value(value="destinationValue")

Comment: What do you mean by `run @Value...` ?? There is no "run" there, it's set at configuration time.

Comment: I want to replace "somevalue" with dynamic variable here (it should not read from property. Instead it should get run time value of a batch job execution id. Is it possible?):        Like this @Value(value=#{somebean.somevariable})  INSTEAD OF  @Value(value="somevalue")     somevariable value will be set initially one value & later I will reassign. Is it possible. I get null pointer if I just assign a beanvariable. If I assign some value in initial, it takes that only

Comment: No; it can't change at runtime, `@Value` is evaluated once, during context startup. If you need to change queues dynamically at runtime, you have to create a new channel adapter each time the value changes.

Comment: Ok, At last I decided to go with outbound-channel-adapter where I can have jmsTemplate. & setting jmsTemplate.defaultDestinationName at run time every time I run the job. I got it from another question thread where you answered for the same which was useful to me. Thanks for your help.